# Multiple files with different language

Tags: nodes, files, i18n-l10n

I want to make a field with type file and this field with multiple values, so far I know that its simply possible but I want also to some thing like bundle field with each file uploaded and this field is representing language.

**Example**: Suppose I upload 3 files in same field for the same node & each file with different language (file_1 => English , file_2 => French , file_3 => German) and so on.

So is there any module can accomplish that, or its something I should do custom?

I want a solution like the attached image
[image]

Comment: Why not using translated node for each language? The file field is the only difference between the languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) is the most close solution to what i need

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [field_collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)?

1. Install and enable the module.
2. Add a field of type "Field Collection" to your entity type.
3. Go to admin->structure->Field COllection
4. Add 2 fields
   1 field is of file type
   2 field is either select box with countries or can be taxonomy reference field

Now while creating the content, you will have option to upload a file and select a language for it.

Comment: probably this might do the job, i ll try it and will come back with the result.

Answer (score 0):

The [Entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module should allow you to accomplish this.

A brief series of steps to are listed below but I would encourage you to look at [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1280632) on drupal.org

1. Install and enable the module
2. Add additional languages to your site
3. Enable multilingual support for the content type
4. Make the file field translatable

Comment: i tried the entity translation which is OK, but if there is a module can do as in the attached image it would be the ideal solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could make custom solution by using **delta** as the field will have more than one value

> 0 => English , 1 => French , 3 => German

So when you are viewing that node based on language you could just render each file based on mapping delta with languages.

Also making custom ***field--[type|name[--content-type]|content-type].tpl.php*** take a look [at](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) to control field display

even with views you could alter the [views_query](http://hook_views_query_alter)

At the end you have to handle edit and if the user deleted one file you must make the delta be in its original order.

Answer (score 0):

with file_entity module you can attach more fields to file widget. So when user uploads something he/she can select language. In your case I think you would need also languagefield or create field inside file entity and populate list of enabled languages.

Answer (score 0):

What about **Inline Entity Form** module (https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)

follow the next steps:

1. Create one content type with the file field.  You didn't mention if your site uses multiple languages,  if it does most probably the language field would show up in the form (with the languages that the site is using).  If there is not a default language field you can add a language taxonomy containing the desired languages.
2. On your current form add an entity reference field pointing to the form with the file file, and select inline entity form(multiple values) widget.

Then you can use **Views** to display your info.
Or if you don't want to use views then you can use **Inline Entity Display** module (https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_display)